# Can I use a CAT28LV64 at 5V?

Tags: voltage, cmos, eeprom

I'm trying to find good EEPROM/Flash memory that I'm able to use on a breadboard for preferably cheaper than $12. I came across the CAT28LV64 and noticed that it fits very well with my needs. The only concern is it says it uses 3.3V, while what I'm using it for will be using 5V. I did notice in the [datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/343/CAT28LV64LI20-pdf.php), however, that it says VCC can be up to +7V maximum. Does this mean I'm able to power it with +5V and get roughly +5V output? I'm still very new to the electronics side (I'm much better at the logic side) so my understand of electronics is still quite rough.

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the device.

Comment: Since the "LV" implies Low Voltage, probably no. I'm guessing you were looking at the "Abs Max" table in the datasheet : it's not guaranteed to function at Abs Max voltage, just not die.

Comment: why are you posting a link to a third party datasheet archive when the datasheet is available on the manufacturer's website? ... https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cat28lv64-d.pdf

Comment: "Absolute Maximum" ratings are NOT an operating spec! The datasheet tells you that right there immediately underneath the table: "**Maximum Ratings are stress ratings only. Functional operation above the Recommended Operating Conditions is not implied**"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't be used at 5V because it is a 3.3V part.

It is rated to operate under a supply voltage range of 3.0V to 3.6V.

Operation outside this range is not guaranteed in any way and it does not have to operate normally or properly outside that range, and using it outside the range may affect the long term reliability of the part.

The 7V is an absolute maximum rating after which it can be permanently damaged immediately.